# Inserting a rank in sequential order for grouped records in a table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to look for the best way to assign values to records in a table starting with the value 1 and incrementally going forward by the value 1.  The table contains records on a date by date basis for which there are multiple records per date.  I need a solution (perhaps a loop) that will go date-by-date and insert a rank number for each starting with the number one and incrementing itself by one for each record.  As soon as a new date is identified, I need to start with the value one again.  For example if I have the following 6 records with the 4 fields 'Date', 'User', 'User ID' and want update the field 'sequence' using this logic, my code will (1) group all records by date, (2) sort by user ID and (3) reveal the following result in the field 'Sequence':

```
Date         | User      | User ID | Sequence
4 September  | Mary      |    09   | 1
4 September  | Bob       |    58   | 2
4 September  | Dave      |    59   | 3
5 September  | Drew      |    32   | 1
5 September  | Steve     |    35   | 2
6 September  | Mary      |    09   | 1
```

I realise I need to do some type of loop on a day-by-day basis but need help getting started.

Comment: I'm guessing you have an 'uncommited' change in process. Would need to see the code and know what steps you take to create the error.

Comment: I agree with Wayne. You will need to provide a lot more information than you have in order for anyone to be able to provide any help.

Comment: For the date 4 Sept., what is the logic which determines Mary (instead of Bob or Dave) should be assigned Sequence 1?

Comment: The logic is and ID number associated with the user.  I will edit the above to be more clear. Good catch Hans

Comment: My impression is you want a VBA procedure to compute and store *Sequence* values which reflect the state of the data when that procedure is run.  If so, that means the stored *Sequence* values will not reflect subsequent changes (`INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`) until you run the VBA procedure again.  Is that what you really want?

Comment: Yes thats right. Basically that table will be created over and over again and the users and dates can grow. The last step of the routine i need is code that will perform and update query to the field 'Sequence' (which will be blank) assigning the autonumber starting with 1 as the initial value.

Comment: Can there be more than one record for the same user on a single date?  Like 2 records for Mary on Sept 4?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65038/discussion-between-marchese-il-chihuahua-and-hansup).

Comment: Storing that value in the table is generally a bad idea.  It breaks one of the first rules of database normalization.  What is your ultimate goal here?  If you let us know what you are doing with this we may be able to provide a better alternative (@HansUp has already proposed a better alternative in his answer below).

Comment: Thanks MWolfe. I have been studying database programming consistently for a while now and one of the biggest gap areas stills seems to be where my lack of knowledge on querying and storing data forces me to have to create 'holding-type tables' to extract data, run queries to it and then rund mor queries to elaborate the data and get the value i need in the format i need..  My example above is quite simple, my final objective is to have each of those records sequentially numbered so that i can then start from number one and past it to a column, take number two and paste it to an adjacent column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! No need to keep looking. The following loop routine is exactly what i needed to resolve this problem. Applying this to my 'generic/theory' example above, you can see how the 'sequence' field above is reflected by the field 'ID_Event' in the below routine. The loop checks the prior record to and if it is has the same date ('Effective Date') it adds 1 to the field 'ID_Event'

```
Private Sub Comando197_Click()

Dim sql As String
Dim varEffective_Date As Date
Dim NumberOfTimes
Dim varID_Event As Integer

sql = "select ID_Event,ID_ValueAddWaste,Effective_Date,ValueAddType,ValueAddType02 from tblPerformanceTrackingMaster03 where tblPerformanceTrackingMaster03.[ID_Event]=0 order by ID"

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open sql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic

Dim counter As Integer
counter = 1

Do While Not rs.EOF

If counter > 1 Then

    If varEffective_Date = rs!Effective_date Then
    rs!ID_Event = varID_Event + 1

    End If
End If

varEffective_Date = rs!Effective_date
varID_Event = rs!ID_Event

rs.MoveNext
counter = counter + 1

Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely must store *Sequence* values, use an `UPDATE` query with a `DCount` expression to compute *Sequence*.

```sql
UPDATE tblMarchese
SET [Sequence] = DCount(
    '*',
    'tblMarchese',
    '[Date]=' & Format([Date],'\#yyyy-m-d\#') &
        ' AND [User ID] <= ' & [User ID]
    );
```

That query is simpler and could be much faster than opening and walking a recordset to update your stored *Sequence* values.

However reconsider whether you absolutely must store *Sequence* values in the first place.  You could use a `SELECT` query to compute them any time you need to see them, and that would ensure the *Sequence* values you see are always consistent with the latest changes to the underlying data.

Using your sample data with the query below, this is my result set in Access 2010:

```
Date        User   User ID Sequence
----------- ------ ------- --------
4 September Mary         9        1
4 September Bob         58        2
4 September Dave        59        3
5 September Drew        32        1
5 September Steve       35        2
6 September Mary         9        1
```

```sql
SELECT
    m1.Date,
    m1.User,
    m1.[User ID],
    (
        SELECT Count(*)
        FROM tblMarchese AS m2
        WHERE
                m2.Date = m1.Date
            AND m2.[User ID] <= m1.[User ID]
    ) AS [Sequence]
FROM tblMarchese AS m1
ORDER BY m1.Date, m1.[User ID];
```